# How to move files in a Hadoop program?

Tags: hadoop

I want to be able to write to multiple directories from same reducer output. I am using MultipleOutput to write to multiple files. Now, I want to move those files to different directories. How to do that in a Hadoop MapReduce program in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Use `FileSystem.rename`. E.g.,

```
    Configuration conf = ...;
    Job job = ...;
    Path output = new Path("your_map_reduce_output_dir");
    // ...
    if(job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path dest = new Path("your_dest_dir");
        return fs.rename(output, dest);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can we also pass a file name as URI in the path in this case ? Basically I want to move a file to different directory but not the directory itself.

Comment: Sure, you can also move a file to another directory.